# menu links redirects back to home page joomla 1.0

Tags: caching, joomla

i am using **joomla 1.0**, when i try to access any page that requires login(say **link_1**) it sends me to login page.

Now i am logged in and then i try to access the same page i.e. **link_1** but i am always redirected to home page, here but rest of the links works fine.

This occurs for any page i try as link_1, the miracle is that everything works fine if i clear browser cache(remember not the server cache) and in FF only.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't remember if Joomla 1.0 has a user cache plugin : check it in your backend
2) I hope for you this website is not in production : this version is unsupported since several years! So if you don't want to get hacked, you should upgrade to the latest version : 2.5.1!

Comment: yes its in a production mode :(  , but found solution here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510963/browser-caching-on-joomla-mainframe-redirect

Answer (score 0):

Finally after spending lots of hours i found a solution.

This is a 301 redirection issue with joomla 1.0 which was fixed in later version.

Check the post below

[Browser caching on Joomla $mainframe->redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510963/browser-caching-on-joomla-mainframe-redirect)